# Package creation in WebMethods

Tags: webmethods

Anybody knows if it's possible to create a new package using a flow service in webMethods developer 7.1. What I want to do is to create a flow service that takes as input a string (package name) and as result it's going to create the new package with the string as name. Does exist anything in developer that I can call from my service and it creates the packages automatically instead of File -> New -> Package?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no public/documented way of creating a new package programatically as far as I know. However, if you don't mind using private/undocumented services, and understand that doing so would not be endorsed by [SoftwareAG](http://www.softwareag.com/), then you can do the following:

- If you can't see the `WmRoot` package in Developer/Designer (this is by design, since it's considered private) you can add the following configuration key to the file `./IntegrationServer/config/server.cnf`:

  `watt.server.ns.hideWmRoot=false`
- Use the service `WmRoot/wm.server.packages:packageCreate` to create a new unactivated package. Unfortunately the inputs and outputs to this (and most other `WmRoot` services) have not been declared, but you just need to add a String variable called `package` set to the desired package name to the input pipeline to call it.
- Use the service `WmPublic/pub.packages:activatePackage` to activate the new package.

For bonus points, you can programatically create new services in your package as well using the service `WmRoot/wm.server.services:serviceAdd` (this is one of the few services in WmRoot that mercifully does declare its inputs and outputs).

---

Alternatively, if you do not wish to use private/undocumented services, you could create your own service to create a new package relatively easily. Since a brand new package is just a collection of empty directories and a `manifest.v3` file, you can write your own service to create these directories and files and then call `WmPublic/pub.packages:activatePackage` to activate it:

- `IntegrationServer/`

  - `packages/`

    - `<package_name>/` - create this directory with the desired package name (MANDATORY)

      - `code/` - create this directory (OPTIONAL)

        - `classes/` - create this directory (OPTIONAL)
        - `jars/` - create this directory (OPTIONAL)
        - `source/` - create this directory (OPTIONAL)
      - `doc/` - create this directory (OPTIONAL)
      - `lib/` - create this directory (OPTIONAL)
      - `ns/` - create this directory (OPTIONAL)
      - `pub/` - create this directory (OPTIONAL)

        - `index.html` - create this HTML file as a placeholder home page for the package (OPTIONAL)
      - `resources/` - create this directory (OPTIONAL)
      - `templates/` - create this directory (OPTIONAL)
      - `web/` - create this directory (OPTIONAL)
      - `manifest.v3` - create this XML file by copying the structure from another existing package (MANDATORY)

As you can see, the only things that are actually required to create a new package is a new directory under the `./IntegrationServer/packages/` parent directory, and a `manifest.v3` file.

An example `manifest.v3` file from a freshly created package in webMethods Integration Server 7.1.3 is as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Values version="2.0">
  <value name="enabled">yes</value>
  <value name="system_package">no</value>
  <value name="version">1.0</value>
  <null name="startup_services"/>
  <null name="shutdown_services"/>
  <null name="replication_services"/>
  <null name="requires"/>
  <null name="listACL"/>
</Values>
```

A final note: if you take this alternative approach of building your own package creation service, just be careful not to create a new package whose name is considered illegal by webMethods Integration Server.